# What's was the original background color of the accepted answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, design

Does anyone still remember it?
It's not exactly "green".

Comment: You looking for the hex?

Comment: @random,yes.Do you still have a record?

Comment: Random has a record in everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hex code was:

```
#E0FFE0
```

Which in RGB is:

```
rgb(224, 255, 224)
```

Comment: The Force is strong with you... how did you find the old hex code?

Answer (score 6):

I think it was "green-ish".

Comment: I tried,seems there is no such color in css?

Comment: I believe you've missed the joke

Comment: I don't want the answer to be a joke.

Comment: MediumSpringGreen maybe.